# how to make the table more beautiful

Tags: python, data-science

I want to add "TOTAL PLAYING TIME: 00:0:0" at the bottom,the commands I tried have been updated below:

```
totalmins = 0
totalsecs = 0
mins, secs = map(int, record[3].split(":")) 
totalmins = totalmins + (totalsecs // 60)
totalsecs = totalsecs % 60
```

shows error something wrong with the indentation

Comment: I believe you can get that functionality out of the `pandas` module with dataframes.

Comment: yes but is there a way that I can get the table without importing any other module except importing csv

Comment: Sure - write the logic to make a text-GUI like you're already doing.

Comment: You can have without importing a module, the only problem is you'll recode what other modules do. 
There are 2 modules interesting on this matter: 
PrettyTable: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable
Tabulate: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate

Comment: I'm new to Python, could you please be more specific

Comment: why don't you just literally print what you want it to look like? e.g. `print("-----")`

Comment: lol but how can I add ----------------- between the first two rows? the title is in the csv file,and I also want to change them all into capital letters

Comment: @Cecilia, please add part of the data values, so I can suggest an approach for achieving so. And please update your output image, because it's out

Comment: For adding this -------, you could only add as the second element inside the print, the only thing would be to find the right size

Comment: @Luan Naufal I just updated my output

Comment: @Cecilia, try adding, before your loop a flag such as `addHeader = true`, and after the first print `if(addHeader): `
`print("--------------")`
`addHeader = false`

Comment: @Ricky Kim  I think I can't just print the line,because I have differnt csv files,the lengths are different, I need the command to be suitble for all the files

Comment: @Cecilia You can just print the line with constant length for all files and adjust spacing for the contents inside the table or adjust the line length depending on contents

Comment: As for your Update, `totalmins` and `totalsecs` are both initialized to zero, and then you set them later, using only `totalmins` and `totalsecs`, while never using the values `mins` and `secs`.  I don't think this is what you intended.  Instead, try removing the lines where you set `totalmins` and `totalsecs` to 0, and then change the last two lines to set `totalmins` and `totalsecs` in terms of `mins` and `secs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do differently is to capitalize the words "TRACK", "ALBUM", "ARTIST", and "TIME", you can print out the header line separately, like this:

```
print("| TRACK", " " * (max_track - 5),
      "| ARTIST", " " * (max_artist - 6),
      "| ALBUM", " " * (max_album - 5),
      "| TIME |")
```

and then, having already printed out the header, you can skip the first entry in your for-loop, simply by changing the first line of your for-loop to this:

```
for i in data[1:]:
```

Update:

As for your Update, `totalmins` and `totalsecs` are both initialized to zero, and then you set them later, using only `totalmins` and `totalsecs`, while never using the values `mins` and `secs`.  I don't think this is what you intended.

I think you're attempting to collect the total playing time by accumulating it in the loop, and then output it in a readable format when the loop is done.

If that's the case, it might be good to display the hours as well.  So consider creating a variable that stores *all* the seconds (I'd call it `totalSeconds`), and then calculating the `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` from that:

```
# Before the loop:
totalSeconds = 0

# Print out the track information, one track per line:
for ...:
    # Inside of the loop:

    # Print out the track information:
    print(...)

    # Collect the run-length time by adding it to totalSeconds:
    mins, secs = map(int, record[3].split(":"))
    totalSeconds += mins * 60 + secs

# After the loop:
hours = totalSeconds // 3600
minutes = (totalSeconds // 60) % 60
seconds = totalSeconds % 60
print("TOTAL PLAYING TIME:  {}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(
          hours, minutes, seconds))
```

Comment: Thanks,and I want to add "TOTAL PLAYING TIME: 00:0:0" at the bottom,the commands I tried have been updated above

Comment: by the loop, you mean the one I created the table?Or a new loop

Comment: @Cecilia:  Yes, the loop that I'm incrementing totalSeconds in is the one that outputs each row of output.  (Sorry about that; I should have made that clearer.)  I just edited my response to make it clearer.

Comment: because now the result of printing(mins,secs) are 3,4,totalseconds are 2024(incorrect)

Comment: @Cecilia:  Are you printing out mins & secs *inside* the loop?  If not, then you'll only see the mins & secs of the last song.  Try putting `print(min, secs, totalSeconds)` as the last line of the loop.  That way you'll see what the program thinks is each song's min & sec, as well as the cumulative totalSeconds.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you want to solve two issues. First how to create a header, second how to make the header top and bottom horizontal lines align with table size. Try the code below. Note the use of ljust to pad the strings to maximum length of a given column:

```
hl_len = max_track + max_artist + max_album + 4
print ('-' * hl_len)

for idx, i in enumerate(data):

    print("|", i[0].ljust(max_track), 
          "|", i[1].ljust(max_artist), 
          "|", i[2].ljust(max_album), 
          "|", i[3],"|")
    if idx == 0:
        print ("-" * hl_len)
```

Comment: so the header "Track" and other three are already in the file, but I want them to be capital letter

Comment: @Cecilia `data[0]=list(map(str.upper,data[0]))`

Comment: @RickyKim Thank you so much,now it's better